# DB2 : Upgrade of DB2 containing wrapped code

Tags: database, db2, obfuscation, db2-luw

If I have a database with wrapped code using [DBMS_DDL](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0057139.html) built in module and this database is upgraded, will the wrapped code be still usable? The reason for asking is this text in the documentation which gives an impression that it is specific to a version of the database. Thanks!

> The result is a string of type `CLOB(2M`) which contains an encoded 
>   version of the input statement. The encoding consists of a prefix of
>   the original  statement up to and including the routine signature or
>   the trigger, view or package name, followed by the keyword `WRAPPED`.
>   This keyword is followed by information about the  application server
>   that executes the function. The information has the form `pppvvrrm`,
>   where:
>
> `ppp` identifies the product as Db2® using the letters SQL
>
> `vv` is a two-digit version identifier, such as '09'
>
> ```
> `rr` is a two-digit release identifier, such as '07'
>
> `m` is a one-character modification level identifier, such as '0'.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that the manual would have a large warning if such procedures were not usable after a DB2 upgrade. I would assume that the version info in the CLOB are explicitly there to allow IBM to support any changes to the wrap algorithm, and *help* with issues such as upgrades, rather than hinder them